# Redireccionamiento extraño al hacer clic sobre un link de mui pagina web

Tags: php, javascript, html5, web

El problema es el siguiente, en mi pagina web manejo un carrito de compras probando un cambio que realice al hacer clic sobre mi carrito me redirecciono a una pagina extraña, la url es la siguiente https://securepay.grupobea.com/mi_dominio/, en esta pagina se muestra un formulario para pagar con tarjeta, me regrese a mi pagina web, intente de nuevo pero ya no volvió a pasar, estuve revisando mi código y en ninguno de mis archivos o links tengo esa url, me parece muy extraño pero no se que lo provoco, nunca me había pasado.

Alguien me sabe porque paso esto y que me pueda ayudar a prevenir esto?

Eso solo pasa al dar clic sobre el link del carrito, no ha pasado en algún otro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Seria bueno que colocaras el codigo del archivo donde luego te redirigue a esa pagina

Comment: Ya agregue una captura, gracias :)

Comment: El código debería estar escrito, no en una captura

Comment: Si te hicieron alguna clase de clickjacking reemplazando la url de tu carrito por un sitio malicioso, entonces no vas a encontrar eso en el código fuente. Se debe inyectar al cargar la página y el vector puede ser por ejemplo una extensión de chrome.